# Создание объекта через Retrofit 2 + Gson

Tags: android, retrofit, gson

Есть следующий json

```
{
  "comments": {
    "4121585": {
      "counter": 185,
      "best": true
    },
    "4121591": {
      "counter": 62
    },
    "4121595": {
      "counter": 59
    },
    "4121596": {
      "counter": 67
    },
    "4121599": {
      "counter": 19
    }
  }
}
```

К нему класс:

```
public class Like implements Serializable {
private Integer mCommentId;

@SerializedName("counter")
private Integer mCount;

@SerializedName("best")
private Boolean mIsBest;

public Like() {
    this.mCommentId = 0;
    this.mCount = 0;
    this.mIsBest = false;
}

public Like(Integer commentId, Integer mCount, Boolean best) {
    this.mCommentId = commentId;
    this.mCount = mCount;
    this.mIsBest = best;
}
}
```

Код retrofit 2

```
    final Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("localhost")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

LikeService

```
public interface LikeService {
@Headers({
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-type: application/json"
})
@GET("/sdapi/news.api/{project}/posts/{post_id}/likes")
Call<ArrayList<Like>> getLikes(@Path("project") String str1, @Path("post_id") String str2);
}
```

Как на выходе сделать чтобы в ArrayList хранились готовые объекты, согласно {"4121585":{"counter":185,"best":true}

4121585 - mCommentId

counter - mCount

best - mIsBest

Сейчас падает с экспшеном, как я понимаю Gson не знает что делать с таким json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Response {

    @SerializedName("comments")
    private Map<String, Comment> comments;

    public Map<String, Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(Map<String, Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Comment {

    @SerializedName("counter")
    private Integer mCount;

    @SerializedName("best")
    private Boolean mIsBest;

    public Comment() {
        this.mCount = 0;
        this.mIsBest = false;
    }
}
```

---

```
Call<Response> getLikes(@Path("project") String str1, @Path("post_id") String str2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Создавайте, не `ArrayList<Like>`, а `HashMap<String,Like>` либо можно переопределить,как будет разбираться ответ.

```
Call<HashMap<String,Like>> getLikes(@Path("project") String str1, @Path("post_id") String str2);
```

Comment: Да при таком варианте не падает, но получается что HashMap состоит из 1 элемента. Я думаю нужно как-то "вырезать" comments блок

Comment: @user_21 вы всегда можете перед записью в Бд или куда либо еще сделать из вашей мапы все что угодно.